# Android application that adds a signature to a document

Tags: java, android

I have to write an android application that allows users to add a signature to a document.

I do not know how to do it.
Is there an api java that allows to do it or something that I can use in my application?

Comment: Please edit your question explain, in **detailed programming terms**, what "add a signature to a document" means.

Comment: you probably need gesture builder.

i think this link.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html

will be usefull to you. if you need to check the signature again.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a Signature pad below the document like this:-

Step 1) Add this in build.gradel `compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.0`

2) Add this in layout file below your document

```
<com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad
            android:id="@+id/signature_pad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            app:penMinWidth="5dp" />
```

3) Initialize view in android `mSignaturePad = (SignaturePad) findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);`

4) Create function to save signature as Bitmap `createBitmapSvg();`and put this below code

```
private void createBitmapSvg()
{
    Bitmap signatureBitmap = mSignaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();
    if (addJpgSignatureToGallery(signatureBitmap))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(AgreementSignature.this, "Signature saved into the Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(AgreementSignature.this, "Unable to store the signature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (addSvgSignatureToGallery(mSignaturePad.getSignatureSvg()))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(AgreementSignature.this, "SVG Signature saved into the Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(AgreementSignature.this, "Unable to store the SVG signature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public boolean addJpgSignatureToGallery(Bitmap signature) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/Files";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + String.format("Signature_%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
        saveBitmapToJPG(signature, photo);
        scanMediaFile(photo);
        result = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private void scanMediaFile(File photo) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    AgreementSignature.this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

public boolean addSvgSignatureToGallery(String signatureSvg) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        File svgFile = new File(getAlbumStorageDir("SignaturePad"), String.format("Signature_%d.svg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(svgFile);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
        writer.write(signatureSvg);
        writer.close();
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        scanMediaFile(svgFile);
        result = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you need any more help you can comment here.